# How to send JSON to Flash from Node.js

Tags: json, flash, node.js, serialization, remoteobject

I want a simple example of how to send data from a nodeJS server as JSON to Flash, then Flash decodes the JSON. This is part of what I want:

**Server**

```
json = {name : "Person", id: "1"}
```

**Flash**

```
myinput.text = json.id + ":" + json.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AMF.js](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/07/07/amf-js-a-pure-javascript-amf-implementation/), which is the subject of a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530605/amf-messaging-to-zynga-games-error-passed-a-non-zid-to-snapi) which discusses the syntax and debugging process.

Answer (score 0):

On server-side:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    //Some code with error here...

    errorModel = {
        code: 400,
        message: 'Wrong username or password'
    }

    req.flash('error', JSON.stringify(errorModel))
    res.redirect('/login')
})
```

On client-side (for example using **EJS** view):

```
<% if (messages.error) { %>
    <p>
       <%= JSON.parse(messages.error).message %>
    </p>
<% } %>
```